# Interface method shadowing Java

Tags: java, interface, shadow

I am having some interesting problem with interfaces, please help me understand this concept.

I have three interfaces Itest, Itest3, Itest4. Interface Itest extends both Itest3 and Itest4 interfaces.
They both interfaces have common one method `public void one();` Now a class Test implements Itest interface and overrides method `one()`

Now of which interface it inherits method of? What if I want to inherit common method of specific interface.
And 
What effect it has on polymorphism ? what if another class only inherits Itest3 only. I think this will break at runtime.

Please help me understand what the advantage is of that?

Code is here...

```
public interface ITest extends Itest4,Itest3 {
    public static interface ITest2{

    }
}

public interface Itest3 {
    public void one();
}

public interface Itest4 {
    public void one();
}

public class Test implements ITest {    

    @Override
    public void one() {
        //Which interface method it overrides?
    }

public static void main(String... arg) {
        new Test();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: it doesn't matter.

An interface is just declarations, not code. Both interfaces declare a method `public void one()`. When you have an implementing class which implements this method, it implements it for both interfaces at the same time. This implementation in `class Test` doesn't override anything. It's the first implementation. There are no implementations in the interfaces it could override - just two identical declarations for it.

When another class implements ITest3, it will need its own implementation for `public void one()`. Just like any other class which implements ITest4, or ITest. The only case where you wouldn't need an own implementation, is when you would have a class which extends the class Test, because it could inherit the implementation from Test.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration

```
public interface Itest3 {
    public void one();
}
```

Simply states that any implementer of Itest3 will provide a method that is named one, takes no arguments, and returns void.

In exactly the same way

The declaration

```
public interface Itest4 {
    public void one();
}
```

also states that any implementer of Itest4 will provide a method that is named one, takes no arguments, and returns void.

Interfaces simply exist to specify a behavioral contract, irrespective of the implementation of said behavior. 
Thus,

```
public class Test implements ITest {    

    @Override
    public void one() {
        //Defines the behavior of both interfaces
    }
}
```

Defines a class which implements both interfaces.
This is because the method implementation satisfies the requirements of both interfaces.